# Boto3: Difference between (EC2)KeyPair and KeyPairInfo

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Can anyone point me what is the purpose of `Boto3`(resource-level) `KeyPair` and `KeypairInfo` objects? Documentation is yet again vague..

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
key_pair = ec2.KeyPair('name')
key_pair = ec2.KeyPairInfo('name')
```

Importantly, `KeyPairInfo` does not work at all: `AttributeError: 'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'KeyPairInfo'`

**Additionally:**

Both cannot create a new keypair, then why do we have them at all?

print *key_pair_info.key_material*
`AttributeError: 'ec2.KeyPairInfo' object has no attribute 'key_material'`. This is because `key_material` is given to user once while creation.

Just for info, I mostly work with `botocore(client)`

Answer (score 1):

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
ec2.KeyPair('name')  # Get the key fingerprint AND the private key
ec2.KeyPairInfo('name') # Get the key fingerprint ONLY


ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
mykeypair = ec2.create_key_pair(KeyName='name') # Create a new keypair
print mykeypair['KeyMaterial']
```

Comment: `response = ec2.KeyPair('name')` does not return private key; only returns fingerprint and name. Although documentation states it returns `response.key_material`, however this is false because aws does not store private key [http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#keypair]

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the KeyPairInfo directly, but you can get it using this:

```
key_pairs = EC2_RESOURCE.key_pairs.filter(
    KeyNames=[
        'my-ssh-key-pair',
    ],
)

for key in key_pairs:
    print(f'SSH key "{key.key_name}" fingerprint: {key.key_fingerprint}')
```